# How to send simple plane text in volley put request

Tags: android, api, android-volley

hello everyone im using volley for making API calls json request working good .

but now in one task i need to send simple plane text in volley  that is simple device token for push notification.

Here is my code please anyone can modify it for me.

**No response or no error showing by this**

```
 private void updateDeviceToken() {

        SharedPreferences settings = getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences("DEVICE_TOKEN_PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        final String DeviceToken = settings.getString("DEVICE_TOKEN_STRING", null);

        String URL = OrganizationModel.getUserBaseUrl() + dBhelper.getUserID() + "/fcm";

        Log.i(TAG, URL);

        try {

            final String token = GetApiAccess();

            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

            StringRequest jsonObjectRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.PUT, URL,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Update Success");
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            String json = null;
                            NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
                            if (response != null && response.data != null) {
                                switch (response.statusCode) {
                                    case 400:
                                        json = new String(response.data);
                                        json = new DataHelper().trimMessage(json, "message");
                                        if (json != null) new DataHelper().displayMessage(json);
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }) {

                @Override
                public String getBodyContentType() {
                    return "application/text; charset=utf-8";
                }

                @Override
                public byte[] getBody() {
                    try {
                        return DeviceToken == null ? null : DeviceToken.getBytes("utf-8");
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                        VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s",
                                DeviceToken, "utf-8");
                        return null;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    headers.put("Authorization", "Basic " + token);
                     //headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                    // headers.put("Content-Type", "application/text");
                   //  headers.put("charset", "charset=utf-8");
                    return headers;
                }
            };
            requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: SO which  type error you getting?

Comment: You can answer your questions below in the "Your Answer" section